# Server 2012 Event log forwarding

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2012

I am having issues getting the Event logs to forward to my collector server.  I have followed various articles on how to set this up and, enabled winrm on the source and wecutil on the collector.  I ensured the collector was in the Event Log Readers Group, and the windows firewall rules were enabled, however the firewall is not enabled.  I have set up the subscription properly with collector initiated and machine account for the user account, however No events show up in the "Forwarded Events" log, and the runtime status fails with the following error:

Error - Last retry time: 10/12/2016 8:55:12 AM. Code (0x80338095): The connectivity test from the push subscription source to the client failed. This can happen if the client machine initiating the push subscription is unreachable from the server machine where the event source is located. Possible reasons include firewall or some other network boundary. Modify subscription to use Pull based subscription.   Next retry time: 10/12/2016 9:00:12 AM.

I haven't found much on the web to troubleshoot this.  Are there any steps I can take to determine the issue, or am I missing something simple?  One technet article talked about a hotfix for 2008 servers, mine are all 2012.  Could it be GPO related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the following article to troubleshoot various parts of the process.
http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_7/forwarding-events-(part-2)---how-to-troubleshoot-event-forwarding---how-to-configure-event-forwarding-in-workgroup-environments.aspx

Ended up deleting the subscription and re-creating it and the events started to forward.

Comment: I had to edit the log size and destination as it filled my HDD.  Once I deleted the log and changed the size, the runtime test now fails.  I have ensured the services that need to run are started, I checked the firewall settings, tried creating a new subscription, I and even bounced the collector server and run time still fails.

Comment: According to all documentation, it says under "event delivery optimization" to select minimize latency.  Runtime status fails.....when I select normal, the runtime status connects and events are forwarded.

Comment: Your last comment just fixed it for me. How frustrating. If you set it up the Microsoft says to do it, it won't work!

Comment: and If I need to put "minimize latency" there's any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the `Event Delivery Optimization` back to `Normal`, then ran the command `wecutil gr <Subscription name>` and it looked like it worked.